# About the eigenvalues and singular values of this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let be
$T_n=\begin{bmatrix}0&...&0&1&...&1\\ \vdots&&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\0&...&0&1&...&1\\1&...&1&0&...&0\\\vdots&&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\1&...&1&0&...&0 \end{bmatrix}$, proof that the eigenvalues of $T_n$ are $0,-n,n$.

### My proof

$p(\lambda)=det(\lambda I-T_n)=det\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda^2-n&-n&...&-n\\-n&\lambda^2-n&...&-n&\\ \vdots&&\ddots&\vdots\\-n&&...&-n
\end{bmatrix}$
Let $D=diag(\lambda^2,...,\lambda^2)$ and $v$ the column vector with $n$ ones, note that
$\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda^2-n&-n&...&-n\\-n&\lambda^2-n&...&-n&\\ \vdots&&\ddots&\vdots\\-n&&...&-n
\end{bmatrix}=D-nvv^T$, we have that $det(D-nvv^T)=det(D)-nv^TAdj(D)v=\displaystyle\prod_{j=1}^{n}\lambda^2-n\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\displaystyle\prod_{k\neq i}^{n}\lambda^2=\\=\lambda^{2n}-n(n\lambda^{2(n-1)})=\lambda^{2n}-n^2\lambda^{2(n-1)}=\lambda^{2(n-1)}(\lambda^2-n^2)$

### Question

the afirmation $det(A+uv^T)=det(A)+v^TAdj(A)u$ I found in Wikipedia [Matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma), but I don't have able to proof it then I try to proof that if $\lambda$ is nonzero then $\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda^2-n&-n&...&-n\\-n&\lambda^2-n&...&-n&\\ \vdots&&\ddots&\vdots\\-n&&...&-n
\end{bmatrix}$ is nonsingular and so I can use that $det(A+uv^T)=det(A)(1+v^TA^{-1}u)$ that is easier to proof, I think the problem is calculate $det\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda^2-n&-n&...&-n\\-n&\lambda^2-n&...&-n&\\ \vdots&&\ddots&\vdots\\-n&&...&-n
\end{bmatrix}$, there exist a alternative way to calculate it?

Comment: You could give examplary Eigenvectors to the given Eigenvalues. They are quite easy to find. 
As the matrix is symmetric the singular values are the same (in absolute value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  Here's one simple way:
$T_n=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf 0& \mathbf 1_n\mathbf 1_n^T \\ \mathbf 1_n \mathbf 1_n^T&\mathbf 0\end{bmatrix}$

$T_n$ is real symmetric, $\text{rank}\big(T_n\big)=2$ and $\text{trace}\big(T_n\big)=0$
$\implies \lambda_1\in \mathbb R_{\gt 0}\text{ and } \lambda_2 = -\lambda_1\text{ and } \lambda_k = 0$ for $3\leq k\leq 2n$

$2\lambda_1^2 =\lambda_1^2 + \lambda_2^2 + 0+....+0= \Big\Vert T_n\Big\Vert_F^2 = 2\cdot \Big\Vert \mathbf {11}_n^T\Big\Vert_F^2 + 2\cdot \Big\Vert \mathbf 0\Big\Vert_F^2 = 2n^2$
$\implies \lambda_1 =n\text{ and } \lambda_2= -n$ and all other eigenvalues are $0$ as desired.

Answer (score 1):

We can find $2n$ eigenvectors and the corresponding eigenvalues.

$$
v_1=(1,1,\ldots,1) \quad\text{corresponds to the eigenvalue}\quad \lambda_1=n
$$
$$
v_2=(1,1,\ldots,1,-1,-1,\ldots,-1) \quad\text{corresponds to the eigenvalue}\quad \lambda_1=-n
$$
If
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}
1&1&1&\cdots &1&1 \\
1&1&1&\cdots &1&1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &&\vdots&\vdots  \\
1&1&1&\cdots &1&1 
\end{array}\right)
$$
and $Aw=0$, then
$$
T_n\binom{w}{w}=T_n\binom{w}{-w}=0.
$$
There are $n-1$ linearly independent such $w$'s:
$$
(1,-1,0,0,\ldots,0),
(1,0,-1,0,\ldots,0),
(1,0,0,-1,,\ldots,0),\ldots,
(1,0,0,,\ldots,-1,0),
(1,0,0,,\ldots,0,-1)
$$
and hence $2n-2$ linearly independent vectors corresponding to the eigenvalue 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors by the definition.

Let $J_n$ be the $n\times n$ matrix with all ones. Then you can write your matrix as
$$
T_n=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & J_n \\ J_n & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Write a $2n$-vector as $\left[\begin{smallmatrix} x \\ y \end{smallmatrix}\right]$ where $x,y$ are $n$-vectors. Then the eigenvector equation is
$$
T_n\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} J_n y \\ J_n x\end{bmatrix}
= \lambda\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}
$$
Thus we need $J_ny=\lambda x$ and $J_nx=\lambda y$. We easily get
$$
J_n^2x=\lambda^2 x,\qquad J_n^2y=\lambda^2y
$$
Since $J_n^2=nJ_n$ and at least one among $x,y$ is nonzero, we see that $\lambda^2/n$ has to be an eigenvalue of $J_n$.

The eigenvalues of $J_n$ are $0$ with multiplicity $n-1$ and $n$ with multiplicity $1$.

Therefore $\lambda\in\{0,n,-n\}$. It's not difficult to show that each of them is an eigenvalue of $T_n$, by taking suitable vectors $x,y$.

Note that the rank of $T_n$ is $2$, so the zero eigenvalue has geometric multiplicity $2n-2$. Since there are other two eigenvalues, the algebraic multiplicity of $0$ cannot exceed $2n-2$ and so is $2n-2$; $n$ and $-n$ have multiplicity $1$.

Since $T_n$ is a symmetric matrix, its singular values are the (nonnegative) square roots of the eigenvalues of $T_n^2$, hence $0$ (with multiplicity $2n-2$) and $n$, with multiplicity $2$.